# Something wrong with text color and <p> <h4> HTML tags in TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

I need to insert black text using html code in `TextView`.
Here is what I have done.

```
String html="<font color='#000000'> <p><i>bla bla bla</i></p> <h4>bla bla bla</h4> </font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

The result is correct, except for the text color, that is grey instead of black.
I have noted that if I remove `<p>` tags and `<h4>` tags the color becomes black, but of course the overall result is not what I want.

So, how can I keep the aspect and make the text color black?

Comment: there might some css that overlaps it to Gray

Comment: the `font` tag is deprecated in html4 and a non-confrming feature in html5, you shouldn't be using it.  Also do you have a style sheet attached to the site that is overriding the colours for `p` and `h` tags?

Comment: @Daniele Vitali try my updated answer !

Comment: No style sheets in the code.

Comment: I have the same. In TextView's all <p> and <h1> tags will have their inner text grey... Why??? I don't want to overwrite all p and h1-h5 tags with set colors... My TextView text color is black, but it overwrites it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<font> tag should be used inside `<p>` tag and as well as inside `<h4>` tag
```

so you will have to **use two different** `<font>` tags !

**try following code, it will surely work** , as i have tested it !

Either **use**

```
String html=" <p><i><font color='#000000'>bla bla bla</font></i></p> <h4><font color='#000000'>bla bla bla</font></h4>";
```

**or**

```
String html=" <p><font color='#000000'><i>bla bla bla</i></font></p> <h4><font color='#000000'>bla bla bla</font></h4>";
```

**instead of** `String html="<font color='#000000'> <p><i>bla bla bla</i></p> <h4>bla bla bla</h4> </font>";`

Comment: Yes it works. But there must be a faster solution! Actually I have more <p> and <h4> tags than I have written, and I have to edit all of them. I think there should be a faster solution...

Comment: @DanieleVitali let me check that if is there any such solution exist !

Comment: OK thanks. I googled it and I have found some solutions but no one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that Html.fromHtml() supports only a small subset of HTML -- much less than a WebView. In particular, you can not use CSS style sheets. If your output is going to a TextView via Html.fromHtml(), then your only formatting options are to add font-color, etc. to the old HTML3/4 tags. Commonsware has a helpful list here:[Html.fromHtml() tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below code work for me hope also work for you:

```
Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<font color='#145A14'>text</font>]]>");
```

In your example write this way :

```
String html="<![CDATA[<font color='#000000'> <p><i>bla bla bla</i></p> <h4>bla bla bla</h4> </font>]]";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

Comment: Does not work for me... nothing changed in the text.

Comment: Then you need to write separate font tag for each <p> tag

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with WebView, but a `font` tag is not state-of-the-art, and like `b` or `i` may end at the next block tag `p`.

```
<div style='color: #000000'> <p><i>bla bla bla</i></p> <h4>bla bla bla</h4></div>
```

Comment: Does not work. Nothing changed in the text.